# Sharing Internet Connection in Windows 7 is so much more frustrated than Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, ad-hoc-network

Back to the time of Windows XP, from Properties dialog of my Wireless Connection, I can enable sharing and then select LAN network from the Drop Down List and boom, I can share it with my friend. We just need a LAN cable (either cross or not-cross is OK) and his Laptop will get an auto IP to gain access to internet.

But now with the new Windows 7, everything starts to suck. I cannot see the Drop Down List any more in the sharing panel and my friends Laptop cannot get an automatic IP anymore.

Am I doing anything wrong over there?
How can I gain back the peace I used to have with Windows XP?

Comment: "now with the new Windows 7, everything starts to suck." it's called 'progress' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Windows 7 help on Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing):

> To enable ICS (Internet Connection Sharing), on your host computer:
>
> - Click to open Network Connections.
> - Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click Properties.  If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> - Click the **Sharing** tab, and then select the **Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection** check box.
>
>   **Notes**
>
>   - The Sharing tab won't be available if you have only one network connection.
>   - You can choose whether to select the **Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet connection** check box.
>   - Optionally, to allow other network users to use services running on your network, click **Settings**, and then select the services you want to allow.

Comment: The Windows 7 behavior is a bit funny for me.
If I enable some services in the `Settings` dialog, then the sharing will work as it should. But if I don't check any service, then there's no automatic IP anymore, the sharing won't work.
Thanks.